# when I use something like unique key(element1,element2) how does it work internally?

Tags: sql, mysql

1. If I say `index(element1),
   index(element2)` does it use much
   less space than `unique
   key(element1,element2)`?
2. I know what they do is different. My
   understanding is that `unique
   key(element1,element2)` ensures that
   there are no duplicates where those
   2 rows are the same. Is this
   correct?
3. Does it still index both keys
   individually?
4. But is this expensive in terms of
   disk space and checking to create
   such and index?
5. Maybe it's better to not have it if
   it's not critical there are no
   duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An INDEX(a,b) uses less space than two indexes INDEX(a) and INDEX(b), because each index consists of (a part of) that column and the primary key. But read the note below about the functional difference between these indices.
2. Correct. A UNIQUE KEY makes that no 2 rows have the same values for the columns in that key.
3. A UNIQUE INDEX is also an INDEX and can be used for searching. A special example of a UNIQUE KEY is the PRIMARY KEY.
4. Indexes do take up space on the disk, depending on your Storage Engine. If your application is write-heavy (like a logging table), sometimes it might be better to not have an index. Most tables are probably read-heavy though.
5. From a logical point of view, if it's not critical there are no duplicates, don't put the index.

#### Edit: elaboration on pst's comment:

If you have `INDEX(A)`, `INDEX(B)`  and `INDEX(A,B)`, your `INDEX(A)` is redundant. Drop it
But `INDEX(A,B)` does not cover queries that only search on B, you need an `INDEX(B)`  for that.

You can argument that `INDEX(A)` and `INDEX(B)` together can use MySQL's `INDEX MERGE` to form the `INDEX(A,B)`. This leaves you the choice between

1. `INDEX(A,B)` and `INDEX(B)`
2. `INDEX(A)` and `INDEX(B)`

Solution 2 will take less disk-space, that is true. But read this [Very Nice MySQLPerformanceBlog article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/19/multi-column-indexes-vs-index-merge/) about INDEX MERGE, which comes to this conclusion:

> As a summary: Use multi column indexes
> is typically best idea if you use AND
> between such columns in where clause.
> Index merge does helps performance but
> it is far from performance of combined
> index in this case. In case you're
> using OR between columns - single
> column indexes are required for index
> merge to work and combined indexes
> can't be used for such queries.

Comment: Not a bad answer, however, consider: 1) What is the cost of INDEX(A) + INDEX(B) vs. INDEX(A + B)? 3) See #1.

Comment: `If I say index(element1), index(element2) does it use much less space than unique key(element1,element2)? ` ... OP want to separate into two indexes ...